# Getting the Current year, month and date on python script

Tags: python

I am trying to get only the year output from the below script, but when I check for the same I am getting

`/year=2020-08-20 19:11:26.616679/month=2020-08-20 19:11:26.616689/date=2020-08-20 19:11:26.616690'`

Is there a way to get in `year=2020`, `month=08`, and `date=20` format?

```
year = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now()` is the _entire_ date (and time). If you want the year, use `datetime.datetime.now().year`, and similar for month etc.

Comment: When I try to run separate commands for each year, month, and date, I am not getting the proper output for the date. Getting as below ( /year=2020/month=8/date=<built-in method date of DateTime.datetime object at 0x7f2b8543fa08>)

Comment: You want `day`, not `date`. `date` is a method that gets just the date (day, month, _and_ year) from the date-and-time-object.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date    
print(date.today().strftime('%Y, %m, %d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

With datetime module, you can have something like this

```
from datetime import datetime
year = datetime.now()
print(datetime.strftime(year, 'year=%Y, month=%m, date=%d'))
```